# access script stored in .github directory in github action

Tags: github, github-actions

I have a `my_script.sh` file in `.github/my_script.sh` in my repo.

Below is my YAML file:

```yaml
jobs:
    main:
      runs-on: ubuntu-latest
      steps:
        - uses: actions/checkout@v3
          with:
            path: master
        - name: Set sync script in env
          run: |
            myscript=$(cat .github/my_script.sh) 
            echo "::set-env name=MY_SCRIPT::$myscript"
```

But I got this error:

```
cat: .github/my_script.sh: No such file
```

Any clue why?

Comment: Are you able to `ls ./.github/my_script.sh` locally and as well as on GitHub Actions?

Comment: BTW, what is this line `echo "::set-env name=MY_SCRIPT::$myscript"` doing? Could you please share a reference for this? I have seen `::set-output` but not `::set-env`. And, AFAIK, the `::set-output` has been deprecated, see https://github.blog/changelog/2022-10-11-github-actions-deprecating-save-state-and-set-output-commands/.

Comment: @Azeem that's the cause, solved it, it has nothing to do with path, sigh. Thanks!

Comment: Good to hear that you got it working. Could you please share what you did to fix it or maybe self-answer it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to https://github.com/actions/checkout, `path` is the "relative path under $GITHUB_WORKSPACE to place the repository". Note that does not change the working directory.

This means that using `path: master` will put your repo in a folder named `master`. I suspect that you meant to check out the `master` branch instead. Checkout will automatically checkout the branch the workflow was ran on so most of the time, specifying it specifically is not required.

You either want to remove the path argument or change your code to use the correct path: `myscript=$(cat master/.github/my_script.sh)`

Answer (score 0):

I think specifying working directory will work.

```
jobs:
  main:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    defaults:
      run:
        working-directory: .github
    
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v3
    
    - name: step sync script in env
      run: cat my_script.sh
```

I have checked it and it works.